# Is this patent expired

Tags: us5361739

I know this is a common question but I received a letter from an attorney claiming I have infringed on a patent. I believed the patent in question had expired since the published filing date is 1993 (24 years ago). Is there any way this patent is still enforceable?

In reference to the patent: [US5361739](https://www.google.com/patents/US5361739)

Comment: "I received a letter from an attorney claiming I have infringed on a patent" that's where you should contact one yourself. Though I think this patent has expired .. are they maybe claiming past infringement or something else? Another patent?

Answer (score 1):

From Wikipedia:

> For applications filed on or after June 8, 1995, the patent term is
>   20 years from the filing date of the earliest U.S. or international
>   (PCT) application to which priority is claimed (excluding provisional
>   applications).
>
> For applications filed before June 8, 1995 and
>   for patents that were still in force on June 8, 1995, the patent term
>   is either 17 years from the issue date or 20 years from the filing
>   date of the earliest U.S. or international (PCT) application to which
>   priority is claimed (excluding provisional applications), the longer
>   term applying.

This patent should have expired on May 12, 2013. In any case, faced with such a communication, you should consult with your attorney.

Comment: Infringement allegedly occurring prior to May 12, 2013 may still be within the statute of limitations, if that's relevant to their complaint.

Comment: @Upnorth I'm not a lawyer, so I can't advise you. Best to check in with an IP attorney.

Comment: @Upnorth According to this link, the statute of limitations for patent infringement is 6 years. http://www.ipwatchdog.com/2010/05/27/the-risk-of-sleeping-on-your-patent-rights/id=10777/

Comment: As a lawyer, I assure you I can find and read a statute of limitations and I was in no way soliciting any such advice. The point was that the OP will need to consider those 6 years and the resulting ability of the patent owners to file an action well after a patent's expiration or lapse.

Comment: @Upnorth Sorry about directing the article to you, I meant it to be for the original questioner. I'm not a lawyer, just an inventor so I was unaware of the actual statute of limitations.